# O que são processamentos assíncronos e processamentos síncronos?

Tags: java, android, async

Eu estou tendo esta dúvida enquanto estou estudando sobre a classe *Handler*.

No livro diz que quando uma *Thread* estiver sendo utilizada para realizar algum processamento assíncrono e precisar atualizar a interface gráfica da tela, é obrigado a usar um *Handler*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Processamento assíncrona refere-se a processamentos que não dependem do resultado de outros, e podem, portanto, ocorrer simultaneamente/separadamente. Eles correm em [Threads](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) diferentes.

Em oposição, o processamentos síncronos são executados um a seguir ao outro, o próximo só inicia quando o anterior terminar. Eles correm na mesma *Thread*.

O [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) permite colocar [Messages](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html) e [Runnables](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/define-runnable.html) na [MessageQueue](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) da *Thread* onde foi criado, permitindo que código de uma *Thread* seja executado em outra.

O Android, bem como a maioria dos sistemas, obriga que código que utiliza "objectos da UI" tenha de correr na *UIThread*(*MainThread*).
Quando o código que corre num *Thread* diferente necessita de [actualizar a UI](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html), recorre a um *Handler* associado a *UIThred* para o colocar na sua *MessageQueue* para ser executado.

<sub>**Nota:** O assunto foi aqui abordado de forma simplista, numa tentativa de facilitar a sua compreensão, se quiser aprofundar siga os *links*.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Processamento assíncrono no contexto da sua pergunta é um processamento que leva um certo tempo para executar e (tipicamente) ao fim desse processamento a interface gráfica precisa ser atualizada.

Você poderia simplesmente encapsular esse processamento e a atualização da tela em um método, chamar esse método (a partir da *thread* principal, caso contrário a atualização da tela não funciona) e esperá-lo executar. Isso seria o processamento síncrono. Mas devido ao fato do processamento ser demorado o método irá demorar para executar e a tela perderá a responsividade (não responderá a comandos de toque nem atualizará a interface gráfica) pois a *thread* principal ficará ocupada executando-o. Idealmente a *thread* principal deveria ficar restrita a atualizar a tela e tratar *input* (no caso os ditos comandos de toque).

Por esse motivo você faz o processamento de forma assíncrona: solicita a uma *thread* separada (seja criando uma diretamente, ou então indiretamente através de uma `AsyncTask` ou outro meio) para executar esse processamento e continua seu caminho normalmente, executando outros comandos.

Quando o processamento terminar a *thread* secundária colocará na fila de mensagens da *thread* principal o comando que atualiza a interface gráfica (seja via `Handler`, ou `runOnUiThread()`, ou um método *callback* de `AsyncTask` como o `onPostExecute()`, por exemplo).

Answer (score 2):

Não é necessário implementar um handler, mas é sim necessário criar um thread separada do processamento assíncrono para atualizar a interface gráfica. Você pode fazer isso de forma bem simplificada usando o runOnUiThread. Por exemplo, se você tiver uma progressDialog que precisa ser exibida e escondida no início e fim de um processamento, você faria algo como:

```
//Mostrar dialog de progresso:
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            progressDialog.show();
        }
});
//Esconder dialog de progesso:
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
});
```

O runOnUiThread deve ser chamado por uma activity.