# O que são métodos Async?

Tags: c#, .net, async, assincronismo

Reparei que a maioria dos métodos em C# tem um método igual mas com um nome `async`.

O que são esses métodos e como eles funcionam?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

São métodos que podem executar assincronamente, ou seja, quem chamou não precisa esperar por sua execução e ela pode continuar normalmente sem bloquear a aplicação, assim quando o método assíncrono chamado termina ele pode voltar para o ponto em que foi chamado e dar continuidade ao que estava fazendo. Isso é feito com a palavra-chave `await` que já foi explica em [Em C#, para que serve a palavra chave await?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2793/101). O seu funcionamento é explicado nessa pergunta, ele é basicamente uma máquina de estados que regula a execução entre a linha de execução normal e a assíncrona.

É uma convenção que esses métodos terminem com o sufixo `Async`.

Também já foi falado sobre assincronicidade em [O que são processamentos assíncronos e processamentos síncronos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151216/101).

Um exemplo prático da diferença: [Qual diferença entre ToListAsync() e ToList()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/169733/101)

Provavelmente vai querer saber sobre [Diferença entre Task e Thread](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123173/101) e um exemplo prático do seu uso: [Quais os prós e contras da implementação Task<List<Object>> sobre List<Object>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77759/101).

Em operações que a resposta será muito rápida o seu uso não vale a pena, isto é útil quando há alguma espera, algo como 50ms, mas sempre depende do caso, pode ser menos ou mais. Por isso dizer que a maioria dos métodos possuem `Async` no nome é força de expressão :) Afinal a maioria executa na casa dos micro ou nanossegundos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Então métodos async seria como se tivesse uma thread só para eles?

Comment: @viniciusafx não exatamente. Nesses *links* eu até falo disto, ele nunca cria *threads*. `Task` pode criar *thread* se necessário. Mas a grosso modo tem um efeito semelhante.

Answer (score 5):

São métodos assíncronos como o @Maniero mencionou, somente para complementar a explicação e você compreender melhor, muitas vezes utilizamos `async` para consumir um serviço `Httpclient` em uma aplicação Winforms ou WPF. Por exemplo:

```
static async Task<Product> GetProductAsync(string path)
{
    Product product = null;
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
    }
    return product;
}
```

Este método irá fazer uma requisição do tipo "GET" a um serviço web, para receber esse objeto `Product` sua função ficaria assim:

```
private async void GetProduct(){
 string url = "http://localhost:50500/MyController/MyAction/ProductId";
 var product = await GetProductAsync(url);
}
```

Sempre que você for chamar um método assíncrono o escopo da função deverá ter o `async` antes do tipo de retorno e a chamada da função deverá ter `await` antes do nome do método. Basicamente é assim que eu utilizo esses tipos de funções.