# Como escrever um método assíncrono?

Tags: c#, .net, assincronismo

Tenho o seguinte método:

```
public void Contar()
{
    int numero = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        numero *= i
    }

    return numero
}
```

Supondo que o método `Contar()` demore a ponto de travar a UI de minha aplicação, como faço para tornar o método assíncrono?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar a class **Task**

```
public async Task AguardarContadorAsync()
{
     int retorno = await Task.Run(()=>Contar());
}
```

Como você pode observar que é necessário adicionar a Keyword **async** na assinatura do método.

Mais informações:

[O que são métodos Async?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175304/44289)

[Em C#, para que serve a palavra chave await?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2793/44289)