# Quais as diferenças de usar async e await em backend e frontend?

Tags: assincronismo, independente-de-linguagem, async-await

Quando usamos `async` e `await` no *backend* e *frontend* ? É melhor? É pior?

Outras perguntas relacionadas:

1. Uma API, por exemplo em C#, se todos os métodos são `async` e `await`, posso dizer que é melhor do que se eu não usasse?
2. Quando não é recomendado usar `async` e `await`? Por que?

Comment: Como assim existe diferença de performance? Async/await tem uma finalidade que é aguardar (ou não) ações assíncronas. Tenta contextualizar essas perguntas...

Comment: @FelipeAvelar acho que agora faz mais sentido, obrigado pelo comentário.

Answer (score 4):

Não existe estas relações que está achando que tem, isto é mecanismo da linguagem para trabalhar com execução assíncrona, ele nada sabe onde está executando isto, se é *back* ou *front end*.

Ao contrário da crença popular usar `async` é mais lento que não usar. O que ele tem de diferente é não bloquear a execução e pode dar uma experiência do usuário melhor, mas não conte com sendo mais rápido apenas dar impressão de entregar algo sem impedir outras partes da aplicação de funcionar, o esforço dele é maior que uma execução síncrona.

Se a execução for muito rápida o `async` certamente tornará sua aplicação pior, se demora para responder (dizem que pelo menos 50ms de espera), e isto só serve para operações de IO, então pode dar uma melhor experiência. Se fosse útil para tudo tudo seria `async`. Mesmo quando tam algo `async` em muitos casos é melhor usar a versão síncrona mesmo. Tem que testar e ver se tem vantagem.

Se usar errado, e muita gente usa errado, pode piorar em qualquer situação. Se fizer errado nem adiantar testar.

Pode começar estudar o assunto em [O que são métodos Async?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175304/101). Mas não pare aí (principalmente siga os *links*, veja a documentação, só cuidado porque alguns exemplo tem técnicas para fazer esperar de propósito, não copie o código como se fosse receita de bolo), é algo que precisa bastante entendimento antes de usar.