# Prioridade execução de thread android

Tags: java, android

Tenho o seguinte código para impressão em P.O.S no Android; Antes de chamar passar os dados pra impressão térmica, faço a chamada pra testar se a impressora tem papel ou ta tudo certo com ela.

```
PrinterDemo.getInstance(getApplicationContext(),toast,dialog).testeImpressao();
```

O conteudo do método testeImpressao é o seguinte :

```
public void testeImpressao() throws RemoteException {
        Printer.getInstance().getStatus();

        Printer.getInstance().start(new OnPrintListener.Stub() {

            @Override
            public void onFinish() throws RemoteException {
                Log.d(TAG, "----- onFinish -----");

                SendJsonPayment.eita = "deucerto";
                //hideDialog();
                //showToast(R.string.succeed);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int error) throws RemoteException {
                Log.d(TAG, "----- onError ----");
                SendJsonPayment.eita = "deuerrado";
                //hideDialog();
                //showToast(Printer.getErrorId(error));
            }
        });
    }
```

O problema é que preciso saber se ta tudo certo antes de mandar os dados da impressão porém logo depois dessa linha  `"Printer.getInstance().start(new OnPrintListener.Stub()"` ele sai do bloco e volta pra linha subsequente da chamada do método de teste que é onde realizo o teste se deu certo ou não :

```
if (eita.equals("deucerto"))
```

E depois volta e cai no método `onError` ou seja a minha condição nunca é satisfeita , gostaria de saber como faço pra ele executar logo e me apresentar o erro antes do teste acontecer.

Answer (score 1):

Ao que tudo indica o método `start()` é assíncrono, ou seja, ele delega a execução para uma porção de código relativamente demorada em outra thread e quando termina de executar essa thread chama `onFinish()` ou `onError()`.

Então não faz muito sentido ter código depois do `start()`, onde você diz que está a checagem `if (eita.equals("deucerto"))`, pois a chamada `start()` está apenas delegando a execução para outra parte do código e imediatamente depois dela não é para vir nada de importante que deva aguardar o resultado do processamento.

O código que está dentro desse `if` deveria ser movido para o método `onFinish()`, que é quando ocorre a condição `"deucerto"`.

Da mesma forma, se houver uma checagem por `"não deu certo"` (por exemplo um `else`), o bloco de código correspondente deverá ser movido para dentro do método `onError()`.

Espero que tenha dado para entender.

[O que são processamentos assíncronos e processamentos síncronos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151216/o-que-s%C3%A3o-processamentos-ass%C3%ADncronos-e-processamentos-s%C3%ADncronos)

Answer (score 1):

Assim como [@Piovezan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/357/piovezan) respondeu o método start é assíncrono, logo, eu o sugiro um callback, um callback serve para "call it back" (chamar de volta) quando uma determinada ação assíncrona terminou

Vamos criar um callback, você pode fazer dessa maneira, ou customizá-lo como preferir:

```
public interface ICallback{
      public void onSucesso();
      public void onErro(String mensagem, int codigoErro);
}
```

Agora, você irá verificar se a operação obteve sucesso através do uso do callback, logo, é necessário receber o callback por parâmetro:

```
public void testeImpressao(final ICallback quandoConseguirUmResultado) throws RemoteException {
    Printer.getInstance().getStatus();

    Printer.getInstance().start(new OnPrintListener.Stub() {

        @Override
        public void onFinish() throws RemoteException {
            Log.d(TAG, "----- onFinish -----");

            SendJsonPayment.eita = "deucerto";
            //hideDialog();
            //showToast(R.string.succeed);
            quandoConseguirUmResultado.onSucesso();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int error) throws RemoteException {
            Log.d(TAG, "----- onError ----");
            SendJsonPayment.eita = "deuerrado";
            //hideDialog();
            //showToast(Printer.getErrorId(error));

            quandoConseguirUmResultado.onErro("Ocorreu um erro", error);
        }
    });
}
```

Agora você precisa passar o callback por parâmetro:

```
PrinterDemo.getInstance(getApplicationContext(),toast,dialog).testeImpressao(new ICallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSucesso() {
              //operação realizada com sucesso
        }

        @Override
        public void onErro(String erro, Integer codigo) {
              //continue aqui para tratar o erro
        }
});
```